# Jest how to make sure I get back a string value?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a test that returns a token.

I can not match the token because i get back a  unique token ever time.

I am looking for a method/way to make sure I always get back a stiring.

code so far:

```
describe('getUser', () => {
  it('get user from ICM', async () => {
    const data: IFindCustomerPayload = {
      cardNr: 'carNumber',
      lastName: 'John1',
      zipcode: '10117',
      dateOfBirth: '1984-03-01',
    };
    const resp = await findProfile(data, 'DE'); // returns a token

    expect(resp).toHaveLength(more than 1? ); // make sure it is a string as long it is not empty
  });
});
```

Comment: why can't you mock findProfile?

Comment: this is a integration test so i get a diffirent token back every time. I could mock it but my attempt was to do the integration test first without mocking.

Comment: Have you tried `expect(typeof resp).toBe('string');` ?

Comment: Validate the length of the token too, the length always be the same?

Comment: @MaA please add your suggestion as an answer

Comment: @IICastro the length differs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:
`expect(typeof resp).toBe('string');`